# IPTables rules and networking with problems

Tags: networking, routing, firewall, iptables

I'm using a Fritzbox for normal network and an own installed Router on rpi3 for an own network with openvpn, dnsmasq and iptables. Over the last few years the setup worked good. You can find the script [here](https://github.com/Kasperx/openvpn_autogenerate_and_reconnect/blob/master/reset_iptables_allinone).

- The update is to not only have a route from fritzbox-network to the other, but also other way around to be able to use all devices in all networks.

Wanted setup is to use the openvpn connection transparently in own network with all connected devices with dhcp server. The fritzbox network is not changed from fritzbox-setup but should be allowed to connect to the other network.

I think that it might be enough to create the routes, one in fritzbox-network to own-network and second in own-network to fritzbox-network. Unfortunately those two exist but don't work.

Would somebody be interested to find my problems and a solution? Thanks

Edit

It might be a good idea to see the other option -> route (table). My route cmd shows following infos:

[route table content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKZSB.png)

In my understanding the last route='192.168.178.0 via 0.0.0.0' is wrong because system doesn't have network 0.0.0.0 but 1.1.1.1 (internal, own-networl=router ip).
With both following steps (separated, not increasing) I lost current connection (from 192.168.178.x):

- deleted that route with
  ** `sudo ip route add 192.168.178.0/24 via 1.1.1.1`
  ** (after some minutes got connection again and reset by reboot, so fine again)
- added route with
  ** `sudo ip route add 192.168.178.0/24 via 1.1.1.1`
  ** (didn't get connection again)

Misunderstanding, wrong firewall options, wrong route or magic?

Comment: FYI:  While your way of saving iptables may work the normal way is   **iptables-save >iptables.save**  The rules saved to iptables.save.  Also **iptables-restore <iptables.save**

Comment: Another critical factor, is order of operations, even if you have 100% the correct rules if they are in the wrong order it will have functionality issues.  If you can, one last time, go back to the way that worked, and then try iptables-save to save your rules I would start there.

Comment: Thanks @cybernard.

Comment: Well the rules do their job, just my future (=wanted) plan of connecting both networks (but blocking internet traffic) does not work. In my understanding I need a route for own-network->fritzbox and a default gateway (if not router) for own-network. Correct? That is already enabled but I'm not able to connect other machines in fritzbox-network. Am I missing firewall rules there?
I will check the order of rules tomorrow.

Comment: Sry for misunderstanding. The rules work for normal networking, but never worked for connecting both networks on both ways (fritzbox->own, own->fritzbox). Maybe my target is no firewall issue.

Comment: Your need to add more --log-prefix entries to trace the flow of traffic.  So if you create a rule iptables -I INPUT 1 -s <whatever> -d <whatever> and log that to verify you can see the traffic you want to allow.  Notice the 1, that makes it the 1st rule.  If you see the traffic your looking for delete that and move it to rule 2  ("iptables -I INPUT  2") and so on.  If the traffic disappears then the previous rule is blocking it.  If you don't see the traffic your looking for at all then try logging in the FORWARD chain instead.  If not there then log the OUTPUT chain.

Comment: Question / description edited with more infos.

Comment: I thing I tested wrong way O.o. A test is only valid with a machine that is really connected in own-network to send traffic to there. A theoretical test may not work sufficient if nothing is actually connected there. -Face-palm-

Comment: Test own-network -> fritzbox-network done -> no success, no connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Don't understand, but got it: My Router fritbox was blocking (or not forwarding) traffic (although in my understanding it doesn't handle it, my own router does it. Right?). I set a new route in fritzbox (that is actually also active in own router) and now the I can connect to other machines in other network.

On own router with tcpdump I found out that the traffic will not arrive at second interface what I expected. So it must have been blocked or not forwarded by another machine -> fritzbox. With the new route ([doc](https://avm.de/service/wissensdatenbank/dok/FRITZ-Box-7590/581_Statische-IP-Route-in-FRITZ-Box-einrichten/)) it works now.